# Speed of an Internal File Transfer on a Remote Device (HDD/NAS)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssh, file-transfer, nas

I have a "WDMyCloud" which is a 3TB NAS with a linux based OS. I have attached another external drive to it so I can copy all of its contents. The second drive was mounted automatically and shows up in windows as another folder for the "MyCloud".

Is it faster to SSH into the MyCloud to copy the files (cutting my Windows 7 PC out of the loop), or is it just as fast to copy files using the network share mounted in Windows?

Comment: I'd say try both method and see how you go. I think (note: think, I haven't tested this) that SSH directly to the NAS and let the NAS copy internally from the ext-HDD into itself will be faster as the process done internally rather than being done by the windows OS... but I can't prove this as I haven't done any testing. At the same time it may not make any difference because the copying speed from the external HDD is slow enough that either method won't make a difference.